# Format Readonly SD Card ( udisks-error-quark, 0)

Tags: partitioning, mount, sd-card, disk-formatting

I got a sd card that i need to format, but i cannot, i tried various answers from questions in superuser and askubuntu but none of them worked. ( before asking, my sd card is unlocked ).

So, how can i format it?

Screenshot:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/051RC.png)

Comment: If "*none of them worked*", then it's likely the card is faulty, in which case nothing we offer can help.

Comment: Flash drives/cards tend to go "read only" if the inbuilt controller detects media malfunction above a (by manufacturer) predefined level.

Comment: Can you test on another computer & OS?

Comment: @FedKad, sorry but i tried it on a lot of computers/phones and OSes and NONE of them worked

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Comment: I already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

If your SD card has a switch on the side, make sure it's not in the "Lock" position.

Otherwise, I'd try `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/mmcblkop1`

You might need to run `sudo fdisk -l` first to identify the drive location, as "mmcblkop1" might change if you needed to unlock it.

But like user535733 said, it could very well be the card if nothing is working.

Comment: I tried it, and it have shown this :
`
mke2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 is mounted; will not make a filesystem here!
`

Comment: so you unmount it and formatted it?